# How to improve load performance of icons and application names?

Tags: android, performance

I have this code to load icon and application name , but it is slow for more than 50 application and it takes 7-8 sec to load , how to load application name and Icon faster ?

```
private void loadApps() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
            mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            InternalDataManager.apps = getPackageManager()
                    .queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

            for (int i = 0; i < InternalDataManager.apps.size(); i++) {

                ResolveInfo info = InternalDataManager.apps.get(i);

                            // PInfo holds name and icon
                PInfo infoP = new InternalDataManager.PInfo();

                infoP.appname = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm)
                        .toString();


                infoP.icon = info.activityInfo.loadIcon(pm);

                infoP.pname = info.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;



            }
        }
```

Comment: That code should take a few milliseconds to run. How have you determined that it is this block of code that is your problem? What did Traceview point out to you, in terms of the specific calls that were slow?

Comment: Load Icons take times , really times

Comment: `loadIcon()` should take very little time. This sample project can bring up a `ListView` filled with launchable items in the blink of an eye: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Introspection/Launchalot

Comment: look at bottom code from Nimit , how can I list application that has Action main and has launcher

Comment: Please see the project I linked to in my previous comment.

Comment: your code is like mine icon.setImageDrawable(getItem(position).loadIcon(pm)); but Nimit Code is really fast , because it gets applicationIcon not ActiviityIcon

Comment: And my code is "really fast" as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This helper function retrieves all installed apps with the application name, package name, version-number and -code as well as the icons. The method getPackages() returns an ArrayList with all the apps. You should try this...

```
class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;
    private void prettyPrint() {
        Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
    }
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
    }
    return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Comment: it list all of service and other activities , I need Launcher Activities

Comment: I agree with Ata 1st code takes 24 sec. Nimits code takes 18 sec. But still without using packageManager is 200 milliseconds.

Comment: newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager()); - is so slow, it should be there a new thread or load the image into adapter using glide and define custom loader and there make this line of code. Folow this: https://medium.com/@debuggingisfun/glide-load-icons-from-applicationinfo-9d82af5624b2